# Swift: pList with "complex" data

Tags: swift, save, plist, nsdata

As I read and tried out :-) I can only save some simple data types on pList files. Nevertheless I like to use structs, classes etc to represent my data. This should be saved as easily as possible to a pList file and gets reloaded.

I see, that NSData is a valid type for pLists. And also, that this is a general data type. So it is a good idea to move/convert/force a struct or class variable into a NSData object to be saved and reloaded? How would that be done?

Till now I'm using something like this for saving:

```
let dict: NSMutableDictionary = ["XYZ": "XYZ"]

// saving values
dict.setObject(myBasicArray, forKey: "BasicArray")

dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
```

**Updated:**
I used the offered code and extended it to handle a struct:

```
import Cocoa

struct SteeringItem {
    var ext    = String()   // extension including dot e.g. ".JPG"
    var bitmap = Int()      // flag for grouping file types, e.g. photos

    init?(ext: String, bitmap: Int) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.ext    = ext
        self.bitmap = bitmap
    }
}

class Foo {
    let one: Int
    let two: SteeringItem


    init(one:Int, two: SteeringItem) {
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
    }

    init?(dict:[String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let
            one = dict["one"] as? Int,
            two = dict["two"] as? SteeringItem else { return nil }

        self.one = one
        self.two = two
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject] {
        var retval = [String: AnyObject]()
        if let
            one = self.one as? AnyObject,
            two = self.two as? AnyObject {
            retval["one"] = one
            retval["two"] = two
        }
        return retval
    }
}

// create struct
let writeStruct = Foo(one: 1, two: SteeringItem(ext: "one",bitmap: 1)!)
print(writeStruct, "\n")

// write to plist
let writeDict = writeStruct.toDictionary() as NSDictionary
let path = ("~/test.plist" as NSString).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
writeDict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

// print contents of file
print(try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

// read plist and recreate struct
if let
    readDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:AnyObject],
    readStruct = Foo(dict: readDict) {
    print(readStruct)
}
```

but this does not write anymore. With String it worked, with "struct SteeringItem" it doesn't!

**Update 2: class instead of struct**

```
    class SteeringItem : NSObject, NSCoding {
    var ext    = String()   // extension including dot e.g. ".JPG"
    var bitmap = Int()      // flag for grouping file types, e.g. photos

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(ext,    forKey: "ext")
        aCoder.encodeObject(bitmap, forKey: "bitmap")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let ext    = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("ext")    as! String
        let bitmap = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("bitmap") as! Int

        self.init(ext: ext, bitmap: bitmap)
    }

    init?(ext: String, bitmap: Int) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.ext    = ext
        self.bitmap = bitmap

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your data, it might be worth checking out `CoreData` to see if it's a more appropriate fit.

Comment: You don't need a failable `init` if it can't fail. For that matter, if a `struct` doesn't have any `init` methods defined it has a default `init` which does memberwise initialization. Thus you don't need an `init` method in your `SteeringItem` `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to do this, you can adhere to the `NSCoding` protocol or you can write methods to convert your class/struct to a Dictionary and serialize from there.

Here's a good intro to using the [`NSCoding` protocol](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

As for converting to and from a Dictionary the usual way is to provide a failable `init` method that takes a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` which validates and copies the key:value pairs to the member variables. You also provide a method that returns a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` with the same key:value pairs as the `init` takes. Then you can serialize by calling the create method and serializing the resulting `Dictionary`, you deserialize by reading into a  `Dictionary` and passing that in to the `init` method.

Here's an example of the conversion:

```
/// Provides conversion to and from [String: AnyObject] for use in serialization
protocol Serializable {
  init?(dict:[String: AnyObject])
  func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject]
}

struct SteeringItem {
  // Changed var to let, it's a good practice with a simple struct
  let ext    : String   // extension including dot e.g. ".JPG"
  let bitmap : Int      // flag for grouping file types, e.g. photos
}

struct Foo {
  let one: Int
  let two: SteeringItem
}

// Add serialization to structs

extension SteeringItem: Serializable {
  init?(dict:[String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let
      ext = dict["ext"] as? String,
      bitmap = dict["bitmap"] as? Int else { return nil }
    self.ext = ext
    self.bitmap = bitmap
  }

  func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var retval = [String: AnyObject]()
    if let
      ext = self.ext as? AnyObject,
      bitmap = self.bitmap as? AnyObject {
      retval["ext"] = ext
      retval["bitmap"] = bitmap
    }
    return retval
  }
}

extension Foo: Serializable {
  init?(dict:[String: AnyObject]) {
    guard let
      one = dict["one"] as? Int,
      twoDict = dict["two"] as? [String: AnyObject],
      two = SteeringItem(dict: twoDict) else { return nil }

    self.one = one
    self.two = two
  }

  func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var retval = [String: AnyObject]()
    let twoDict = self.two.toDictionary()
    if let
      one = self.one as? AnyObject,
      two = twoDict as? AnyObject {
      retval["one"] = one
      retval["two"] = two
    }
    return retval
  }
}
```

Here's how to test it (in a playground):

```
import Foundation

// create struct
let writeStruct = Foo(one: 1, two: SteeringItem(ext: "jpg", bitmap: 1))
print(writeStruct, "\n")

// write to plist
let writeDict = writeStruct.toDictionary() as NSDictionary
let path = ("~/test.plist" as NSString).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
writeDict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

// print contents of file
print(try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

// read plist and recreate struct
if let
  readDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:AnyObject],
  readStruct = Foo(dict: readDict) {
  print(readStruct)
}
```

Results:

```
Foo(one: 1, two: SteeringItem(ext: "jpg", bitmap: 1)) 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>one</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>two</key>
    <dict>
        <key>bitmap</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>ext</key>
        <string>jpg</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Foo(one: 1, two: SteeringItem(ext: "jpg", bitmap: 1))
```

Comment: Wow! I learned so much. Right now I could save my class. Next I will check, if I could reload it. :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: One question: How do I get the class back? Usually I use "if dict.objectForKey("myVar") != nil { myVar  = d.objectForKey("myVar")! as! [String] }" but this fails. Should it be a cast like this: "myVar = MyClass(dict: dict as! [String : AnyObject])!" ?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of reading and writing using a `Dictionary`

Comment: I added the code I used and which I could get to work.

Comment: You have to serialize every member variable that you want stored into the plist. The way to do it is to create a protocol which requires the two serialization functions, then have your classes adopt it. When you want to store a member variable you call the method and store that in the `Dictionary` to be serialized

Comment: OK, as far as I know, I need to create NSCoder functions, so I changed struct to class to inherit that stuff. Then I need a init function with call to it's super class. I also included the encode functions. So far so correctly? :-)

Comment: Yes, if you are going with the `NSKeyedArchiver` route then that's correct. I would avoid forced unwrapping and implicitly wrapped optionals, if possible. This means you should use `as?` rather than `as!` in your `init?` method.